# Ajax get column table value to become a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to get column table value to become a variable in javascript to complete a formula: **10 * vHasil_m * 32.03* 1000 / 5**.

I have a query like this:

```
select round(avg(cast(t_dtl.hasil_m as decimal(6,4))),4) as hasil_m from t_hdr JOIN  t_dtl ON t_hdr.headerid = t_dtl.headerid where id_solvent ='NaOH' AND status='ok' AND concentrate='0.0100' AND date_start <='2016-05-01' AND date_finish >='2016-05-01'
```

The query result will be like:

```
| hasil_m     |
| ----------- |
| 0.0100      |
```

I want above column value to become a variable for the formula, **vHasil_m**.

To run that query, i've created a model:

```
function getdata_naoh($datetest){
    $result = $this->db1->query("select round(avg(cast(t_dtl.hasil_m as decimal(6,4))),4) as hasil_m from t_hdr JOIN  t_dtl ON t_hdr.headerid = t_dtl.headerid where id_solvent ='NaOH' AND status='ok' AND concentrate='0.0100' AND date_start <='$datetest' AND date_finish >='$datetest'");
    if($result->num_rows()>0){
        return $result->result_array();
    }else{
        return array();
    }
}
```

and a controller to executed it:

```
function get_NaOH(){
    $date_analysis = trim($this->input->post('date_analysis'));
    $datetest = trim($this->input->post('date_analysis'));
    $datetest = substr($datetest,6,4).'-'.substr($datetest,3,2).'-'.substr($datetest,0,2);

    $dtnaoh = $this->M_tambahan->getdata_naoh($datetest);

    foreach($dtnaoh as $row){
        $data1 .= $row[hasil_m];
    }

    $data =  $data1;
    echo $data;
}
```

Then i create an ajax like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(document).on('change','.no_picno', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        var dt_no = that.val();
        console.log(that.next());
        var col_date_analysis =  that.parent().prev().find('.date_analysis');
        var date_analysis = col_date_analysis.val();

        $.ajax({
                  type :"post",
                  url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/additionals/file/C_utils/get_NaOH",
                  data : { date_analysis: date_analysis, no_picno: dt_no },
                  success: function(data){
                      // code here
                  }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The ajax already work without error, then i create a javascript to run the formula:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTotal() {
        var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  

        for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_vnaoh[]") { 
              var dt_sulfur_vnaoh = obj[i].value;
          };
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_ws[]") { 
              var dt_sulfur_ws = obj[i].value
          };
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_hasil[]") {
            if ((dt_sulfur_ws != '')&&(dt_sulfur_vnaoh != '')) {


              var totalSulfur = 10*vHasil_m*32.03*1000/5;
              obj[i].value = totalSulfur;
            } else {
                obj[i].value = '';
            };
          };
        }
    };
</script>
```

How to declare or initializing the ajax result into variable in javascript to complete that formula ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ajax code you need to create a global variable to store your data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(document).on('change','.no_picno', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        var dt_no = that.val();
        console.log(that.next());
        var col_date_analysis =  that.parent().prev().find('.date_analysis');
        var date_analysis = col_date_analysis.val();

        $.ajax({
                  type :"post",
                  url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/additionals/file/C_utils/get_NaOH",
                  data : { date_analysis: date_analysis, no_picno: dt_no },
                  success: function(data){
                      window.data=data;
                  }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and then after your ajax call, fire your `getTotal()` function, then instead of using `vHasil_m` in your formula use `window.data`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTotal() {
        var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  

        for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_vnaoh[]") { 
              var dt_sulfur_vnaoh = obj[i].value;
          };
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_ws[]") { 
              var dt_sulfur_ws = obj[i].value
          };
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_hasil[]") {
            if ((dt_sulfur_ws != '')&&(dt_sulfur_vnaoh != '')) {


              var totalSulfur = 10*window.data*32.03*1000/5;
              obj[i].value = totalSulfur;
            } else {
                obj[i].value = '';
            };
          };
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, but why i get _totalSulfur_ result **NaN** ? is that mean the ajax still doesn't work properly ?

Comment: probably, try to log `window.data` in the console to see its result

Comment: `console.log(window.data);` return nothing, empty result. is that mean the ajax still doesn't work?

Comment: are you calling the `getTotal` function after the ajax call? i.e. in the success function of the ajax call

Comment: yes, the `getTotal` function run with `onkeyup` in input tag, not in the success function of the ajax call

Comment: you need to call the `getTotal` function inside the success function, because naturally it takes time for the ajax to get the result from the server, so when `getTotal` is called the ajax hasn't brought up the value of `window.data` yet hence it'll always be empty

Comment: The problem was solve, i get **NaN** result because of there is no any records in my database, i've used a wrong database, i was my bad. The javascript and ajax are works fine. Thank you for your help.